# Can I set up mailbox forwarding, or a rule to accomplish this, on an Exchange account through an EWS REST call?

Tags: rest, sharepoint, workflow, exchange-server, exchangewebservices

When an employee leaves the company, we want to have all email forwarded to a colleague to avoid communication lapses, especially with clients. We would like to place the forwarding rule on the account through a SharePoint workflow with a call to the EWS REST API.

I tried a few Google searches and ended up finding some related methods in the API docs, but the closest thing I could find was a command to forward a message directly.

Is there a sane way to do what I'm trying to do, specifically with a REST call? I know this could be set up by Net Ops at the admin level, but we have a specific requirement to do this with a SP workflow. I'm fairly new to SharePoint and web APIs, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

FWIW, we are on SharePoint 2013 and Office 365 Exchange.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your using OnPrem Exchange there is no EWS Rest interface yet (its coming in Exchange 2016). The Office365 REST api's currently don't support creating rules either.

A few other ways of doing this is use Remote Powershell https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff326159(v=exchg.150).aspx and Set-Mailbox https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb123981(v=exchg.150).aspx (see example 1)to set a forward on the Mailbox.

You can use EWS (SOAP) to create an Inbox rule https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff597938(v=exchg.80).aspx . (If you really want you can build a WebService to fount end that and provide it as a REST service).

Cheers
Glen

Comment: Ah good to know. Also, thanks for the links. I will look into these and report back.

Comment: I had suggested the inbox rule approach previously, that was a no go. Looks like we will have to take the PowerShell/Set-Mailbox path. Thanks again!